# Can't calculate end address of the section at linker script

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, linker-errors, linker-scripts

I need to make firmware image with 8K size. Firmware image should have a version word at the end. Area between data section and version section must be filled with 0xFF.

This linker script works fine if test and data sections not too big.

```
MEMORY
{
    PM_RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 20K
    DM_RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x0001E000, LENGTH = 6K
    PM_ROM (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00080000, LENGTH = 256K
    PM_OTP (rx): ORIGIN = 0x000C0000, LENGTH = 8K - VERSION_SIZE
    PM_OTP_VER (rx): ORIGIN = 0x000C0000 + 8K - VERSION_SIZE, LENGTH = VERSION_SIZE
}
SECTIONS {       
    .text : 
    {
        *(.text*)
        . = ALIGN(4);        
    } >PM_OTP  

    _etext = .; 

    .data : {
        _sdata = .;
        _ldata = LOADADDR(.data);
        *(.data .data.*)
        *(.sdata .sdata.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >DM_RAM AT>PM_OTP  

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;  

    .fill : {       
        BYTE(0xFF) 
        FILL(0xFF)       
        . = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data) - 1;        
    } > PM_OTP = 0xFF  

    .version : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __version_start__ = .;
        KEEP(*(.version .version*))        
        __version_end__ = .;
    } > PM_OTP_VER 

    .bss : {
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.sbss .sbss.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >DM_RAM    

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
    _end = .;   

    .stack ORIGIN(DM_RAM) + LENGTH(DM_RAM) - STACK_SIZE : {
        PROVIDE(__STACK_START__ = .);
        . += STACK_SIZE;
        PROVIDE(__C_STACK_TOP__ = .);
    } >DM_RAM    
}
```

But if text + data close to 8K I get the error:

```
cannot move location counter backwards (from 00000000000c2095 to 00000000000c1ffb)
```

If change this string:

```
. = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data) - 1;
```

by hardcoded value like:

```
. = 0x3f;
```

Build completes successfully and all OK.
What is wrong with LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data) calculations?
In listing file it corresponds to 0x3f.

## UPDATE

I have linker script

```
STACK_SIZE = 1024;
TEST_MEMORY_SIZE = 4; 
VERSION_SIZE = 4;

MEMORY
{
    PM_RAM (rwx): ORIGIN = 0xFD000000, LENGTH = 120K
    DM_RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0xFD01E000, LENGTH = 6K
    PM_ROM (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0xFD080000, LENGTH = 256K
    PM_OTP (rx): ORIGIN = 0xFD0C0000, LENGTH = 8K - VERSION_SIZE
    PM_OTP_VER (rx): ORIGIN = 0xFD0C0000 + 8K - VERSION_SIZE, LENGTH = VERSION_SIZE
}


SECTIONS {
    
    .init ORIGIN(PM_OTP):
    {
        . = 0x000;
        *(.init.startup)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.init.traphandler)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >PM_OTP
    
    .text : 
    {
        *(.text*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text.emulate*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >PM_OTP    
    
    _etext = .;
    
    .data : {
        _sdata = .;
        _ldata = LOADADDR(.data);
        *(.data .data.*)
        *(.sdata .sdata.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >DM_RAM AT>PM_OTP
    
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;   
    

    .fill :
      {       
        BYTE(0xFF) 
        FILL(0xFF) 
      } > PM_OTP = 0xFF
    
    .version :
      {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __version_start__ = .;
        KEEP(*(.version .version*))        
        __version_end__ = .;
      } > PM_OTP_VER
    
    .bss : {
        _sbss = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.sbss .sbss.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >DM_RAM
    
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
    _end = .;
    
    .stack ORIGIN(DM_RAM) + LENGTH(DM_RAM) - STACK_SIZE : {
        PROVIDE(__STACK_START__ = .);
        . += STACK_SIZE;
        PROVIDE(__C_STACK_TOP__ = .);
    } >DM_RAM

    _test_memory = ORIGIN(DM_RAM) + LENGTH(DM_RAM);
    _loader_descr = _test_memory + TEST_MEMORY_SIZE;
}
```

Build terminates successfully and I get:
text       data     bss     dec     hex
7700        321    1056    9077    2375

Binary look:

```
00001f10  94 05 0c fd 98 05 0c fd  9c 05 0c fd a0 05 0c fd  |................|
00001f20  a4 05 0c fd a8 05 0c fd  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f30  00 00 00 00 ac 05 0c fd  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  |................|
00001f50  ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001ff0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 60 b8 ee 61  |............`..a|
00002000
```

There are zeros here from 00001f60 to the end. But I need 0xFF.

I added line:

```
. = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.init) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data);`
```

In setion .fill after `FILL(0xFF)` and got error:

```
cannot move location counter backwards (from 00000000fd0c2025 to 00000000fd0c1ffc)
```

Very strange. But ok. I gradually reduce my code volume. And at a certain code decrease, the build begins to be successful.
text       data     bss     dec     hex
7656        536    1056    9248    2420

Binary look:

```
00001ef0  a0 05 0c fd a4 05 0c fd  a8 05 0c fd 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 05 0c fd 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001f20  01 01 00 00 ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
00001f30  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00001ff0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff 50 bb ee 61  |............P..a|
00002000
```

There is a lot of 0xFF in the end. And offset is correctly calculated, because 0xFF goes up to version. But other side 0xFF is empty area that could be filled with useful code.

Comment: Are you sure about this `. = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data) - 1;`. It looks like, you set `.`to the address somewhere towards the beginning of the section, e.g. (8k - 4k - 2k) = 2k. Don't you actually want to start filling after all the `.text`and `.data`? Shouldn't his be rather either `. = ADDR(PM_OTP) + SIZEOF(.text) + SIZEOF(.data)`.. or `. = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - (LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data))`?

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and add the map of the case with `. = 0x3f;`, please?

Answer (score 0):

0x00000000000c2095 is apparently beyond `PM_OTP (rx): ORIGIN = 0x000C0000, LENGTH = 8K - VERSION_SIZE`. Your firmware is too large.

Comment: No it isn't. If I remove filling offset (. = LENGTH(PM_OTP) - SIZEOF(.text) - SIZEOF(.data) - 1;) then build completes successfully and even 0x3f bytes remain unused. But these bytes are 0x00. I need 0xFF.

Comment: 0x00000000000c2095 is also beyond `PM_OTP + 8K`. So it really looks as if the firmware is too large. @TarletskyAndrey Please show the resulting section addresses and sizes.

Comment: SYMBOL TABLE: 000c01b0  d  .text; 0001e000  .data; 000c1fc0 .fill; 000c1ffc .version 
   text 7812;   data  380;    bss  1056;    dec   9248;   hex      2420;

Comment: No firmware is not too large. For large sections I get other errors!
.data' will not fit in region `PM_OTP'
 FLASH memory overflowed !
section .version LMA [00000000fd0c1ffc,00000000fd0c1fff] overlaps section .data LMA [00000000fd0c1f10,00000000fd0c204b]
region `PM_OTP' overflowed by 81 bytes

Comment: Did you try a version of your firmware that uses more than 8K of `.text`, and no or a very small `.data`? -- 8K are 0x2000, and I wonder why you get "overflowed by **81** bytes" when the last used address is 0x...204b, which are 0x4c + 4 = **80** bytes over the limit.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes. I don't not why +1 in result. I allways get 4n+1 bytes owerflowed. It's very strange.

Comment: From the symbol table excerp you showed: `.text` begins at 0xc01b0 and is 7812 large. Its end is therefore at 0xc01b0 + 7812 = 0xc2034, which is clearly beyond 0xc1ffc.